# VBScript, SQL Integrated security, DB Connection Timeout

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a VBScript that connects to a *SQL Server*. I am using integrated security in the connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=servename;Initial Catalog=databasename;
Integrated Security='SSPI';
```

Everything works perfectly when I execute the script by double clicking the *.vbs* file, but when I schedule the *.vbs* file to run through task scheduler, the connection to the database times out.

I have task scheduler set up to run using the credentials that work when executing manually.

I hope this is enough information and someone can help me with what the problem is. Please be kind to this virgin who has gotten lots of answers here before, but has never asked a question before.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: hi, please don't use code spans on things like `SQL Server`, this is not code. For more information, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113/220428

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

Setting Connection Timeout in Connection String

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=servename;Initial Catalog=databasename;
Integrated Security='SSPI';Connection Timeout=300;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice. If you would be a doctor and a patient comes with pain you would tell him to get painkillers and shut up? THere is NO reason in which the standard timeout for a connection is not good enough.

Comment: Ya Your right Defining Long Connection Timeout is Not Good.But My Moto was trace out the problem with Questioner as he said `the connection to the database times out`

Comment: As I said - the doctor that does not are tells the patient to take painkillers. A timeout should never time out, not even over the internet. The default is IIRC 30 seconds, that is plenty. Obviously the solution is to fix the problem, not try to live with it.